# How to receive a message from ActiveMQ broker by it's message id?

Tags: activemq-classic, amqp, activemq-artemis, amqp.netlite

We consume a list of messages from the queue inside ActiveMQ broker and present it to the user so the user can select one message, we are using the .net client implementation based on AMQP.Net Lite (.net 2.1).

[AMQ queue messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFqTC.png)

If the user wants to select a specific message from the queue, not the one which is the next to consume from the queue, is there any possibility to access that message by the 'MessageId' parameter or some other property?

Something like the code bellow :

```
Message msgToSend = new Message();
msgToSend.Properties = new Properties() { MessageId = "8589942532"};
receiver.Accept(msgToSend);
```

The list of messages the user can see from the queue are not accepted so they are still visible in the queue. The idea is to accept the message when the user performese a specific action like clicking a 'save' button.

Comment: Not really clear what you are asking, please update the question with more details

Comment: Hello @Tim Bish, I have updated my question, is it now any clearer?

Comment: It sounds like you need a database rather than a message broker.

Answer (score 0):

You can create additional consumer with [filter expression](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/filter-expressions.html), which naturally would filter by message ID, to receive that message. After receiving the message, this consumer would have to go as it would be of no use.

BTW, you can also use [non-destructive queues or consumers](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/non-destructive-queues.html) to browse the queue without removing messages from it (at least this is available in Artemis, not sure about ActiveMQ Classic).